# Using a bearer token to get a federation token from ADFS

Tags: authentication, federation, adfs

Why is it not possible to use a bearer token from an IdP STS to get ADFS (2.1) to issue a token? All issuedtoken endpoints require a symmetric or asymmetric key in the IdP token.

Is there a specific reason for this?